# How to detect that page was reloaded in selenium (python)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to test webcart in online shop.

So, I submit form and then i see "Please wait" page (that is being automatically reloaded at some period of time; it can be reloaded several times). After that final successful/error page is shown.

I need to retrieve contents of final page, that comes after all "please wait" pages.

How i can achieve that using python webdriver module? How i can detect that page was reloaded, to check if it looks like a "final" page, to check if my test failed?

Comment: Can you wait for the '"Please wait" page' to go away?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WebDriverWait to add an explicit wait, with an automatic timeout, to detect the presence of an element that is on the final pages but not on the "please wait" pages.

You can find an example and the types of waits here:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#waits